# How to create glow effect for textview

Tags: java, android, kotlin, textview, effect

I have an application written in kotlin, in my app have function add the desired user text line. Adding text is relatively easy, but I was asked to add effects to the text. Anyone with any ideas please help me

This is the effect i need to add[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my problem, I will post the answer here for anyone who needs it

```
 tv.setShadowLayer(
                10f,     // radius: The radius of the shadow
                0f,      // dx: The horizontal offset of the shadow
                0f,      // dy: The vertical offset of the shadow
                Color.RED // shadowColor: The color of the shadow
            )

            // You can also customize other properties of the TextView
            tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD)
```